# BadRequest: 400 Syntax error in Bitcoin biquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to download bitcoin data from bigquery public dataset.
I want to download in pandas dataframe with three columns

```
transaction_hash, transaction_timestamp, inputaddress
```

My query

```
   SELECT
  hash,
  block_timestamp,      
  input.addresses
FROM bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions,
UNNEST(inputs) input
WHERE block_timestamp < 1588879614 AND block_timestamp > 1572480000
```

I am getting unknown error repeatedly. how to resolve. i tried even in bigquery ui. hash is a field in the table.

```
BadRequest: 400 Syntax error: Unexpected keyword HASH at [3:3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below instead (for BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  `hash`,
  block_timestamp,      
  input.addresses
FROM bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions,
UNNEST(inputs) input
WHERE block_timestamp < '2017-09-07 13:43:30 UTC' AND block_timestamp > '2017-09-06 13:43:30 UTC'
```